# hadoop hostname can't be resolved by local machine

Tags: hadoop, hostname

I am deploying hadoop 2.6.3 cluster mode on a remote cluster using SSH.

Followed those tutorial online and everything worked except accessing the web ui from local machine.

For example, the resource manager web ui address is http://namenode01-bi-dev/:8050. My local machine can't resovle the **namenode01-bi-dev** so i have to type the ip addreess manually. This make sense because the namenode and datanode hostname are configured only on the /etc/hosts in hadoop cluster.

Within the resource manager web ui, every link pointing to other web ui like the datanode web ui starts with the corresponding hostname which can't be resolved by local machine.

Currently, I can only overcome this by adding all the ip/hostname binding to my local /etc/hosts.

I have tried to set all hostname same as the corresponding IP but this gives me the folloing error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.DisallowedDatanodeException:
Datanode denied communication with namenode because hostname cannot be 
resolved (ip=10.104.90.43, hostname=10.104.90.43):
```

I also tried to set those web ui address on yarn-site.xml using IP address instead of their hostname. But the web ui address still starts with the hostname.

Also, I tried use **hostname** command to change the hostname of namenode and datanode to their IP address. But this doesn't work too.

Is there anything else I can do or configure on the hadoop cluster so that the web ui address it use doesn't start with the hostname but the real IP address?

Comment: Sounds like you need a DNS server between the Hadoop cluster and your local computer, also I believe about 2.7 is the latest version of Hadoop, if that matters to you

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the advice. I'd have to call for colleagues from other group to set up the DNS server and that's why I was wondering is there a way to let hadoop just give link using real IP address.

Comment: You would have to use those IP addresses in the core, hdfs, and yarn XML files instead of hostnames. That's where all those links come from

Comment: @cricket_007 That's exactly what I did. I had set all the address within those xml file to be the IP address instead of hostname. But the webui still gives links start with hostname.

Comment: Hmm. It might be pulling from the `/etc/hosts` file(s)

Comment: I thought about that and made the IP and hostname the same in /etc/hosts and this gave  me the error in the question description.

Comment: You can't set a hostname to an IP address in that file. If you want the hosts to only be resolved by IP, you should delete the corresponding host line from that file. I wouldn't suggest that, though. It'll likely make things worse. So, why exactly do you need to use IP addresses? You said adding the hosts to your local machine makes everything work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well, since there are other colleagues using the cluster so I was trying to make everything work out of the box. It turned out that adding hosts to local for anyone using the cluster is the only way to get this thing settled.

Comment: Depending on your router, and if you have access to modify it, you could set static IP addresses there, and DNS should figure out the hostnames... Essentially, your problem is more related to networking than with the cluster configuration